# Firebase database is not updating the value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to update count in the database of firebase, I am getting the success message but it is not updating the database value, here I have added my code and database structure but it is not updating the value, can anyone please help me why it is not updating my value?  I trying to resolve it since last 1 day but I am not getting it resolved

Code :

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const org_id = body_data.org_id;
const expertise_id = body_data.expertise_id.toString().toLowerCase();  

const ref_colleague = db.collection("organizations").doc(org_id).collection('tags').doc(expertise_id);  
    ref_colleague.update({
      count: 10, //admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),    
    });
```

DB Structure :

[[image: Image Data]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bSut.png)

Comment: You are mixing up firestore and the realtime database. Your code is for firestore but the image of your database is from the realtime database. You have to make sure to use the right code for the right kind of database.

Comment: i am sorry, Can you please help me for that, I am new in firebase so not have much idea about it

Comment: I want to increment 1 in firebase real time database

Comment: it is not a realtime database, it is cloud firestore

Comment: You'll have to choose which database you want to use, and use that both in the Firebase console and in your code. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore